# How to force inih to use an .ini file from a specified path

Tags: c, inih

I'm trying to use [INIH library](http://code.google.com/p/inih/) for one of my pet projects but cannot figure out how to force it to read a configuration file from my home directory instead of the current directory where I'm executing my program. Lets say this piece of code reads my configuration:

```
 if(ini_parse(file_name, handler, &config) < 0){
     printf("Can't load %s\n",file_name);
     return 0;
   }
```

when I specify 'test.ini' as a file_name it looks for the file in the current directory where i execute the program (correct), when i specify '~/.tst/gr8.ini' it cannot find it (actually it still finds the one in the current directory)

Comment: how you specify file_name? by command line argument to program or in config file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad. apparently fopen doesn't understand '~', providing an absolute path solves the problem.